# List of bindings for the Xbox controller in Dragon Age:Inquisition

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

After playing with mouse and keyboard for a while I've decided to switch to using a gamepad now. The game is clearly designed for a gamepad and not for mouse and keyboard control.

One small issue now is that I didn't play the tutorial with a gamepad and now am a bit confused about the finer details. The key bindings menu item is greyed out now, and I couldn't find anything listing which buttons on the gamepad perform which function. I could figure out the basics, but I'm still missing some stuff like e.g. pausing without using the tactical view.

Is there a list of the default bindings for the Xbox controller anywhere in game outside of the game?

Comment: Have you checked the codex? All the tutorial entries should be in there.

Comment: @Kexlox The tutorial codex only contains partial information on that

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link with the xbox one manual. I know it looks like a fishy link so if you want to download it yourself you can go to (http://help.ea.com/en/dragon-age/dragon-age-inquisition/?category=game-play-in-game) and at the bottom left is a link for all the manuals.

http://d2ro3qwxdn69cl.cloudfront.net/manuals/dragon-age-inquisition-manuals_Microsoft%20Xbox%20One_en.pdf

Answer (score 0):

EDIt: ^ Beat me to it.

I was able to find the bindings here. I had the same issue as you: I switched to the gamepad after the keyboard and mouse tutorial and thought I missed out on how to use unmapped abilities. Turns out, I didn't miss anything and you literally cannot use any ability that isn't mapped.

d2ro3qwxdn69cl.cloudfront.net/manuals/dragon-age-inquisition-manuals_PC_ww.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In character record, go to tactics, highlight the skill you want to be on your gamepad, choose (A) for "Map to Battle Menu", then press the button you want it to go to.